# Problems with Insert( simple query - can't think something )

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have 2 tables, `Tblservicedesk` and `Tblservicedesk_temp`

Columns:

- CodServiceDesk
- ID_Solicitacao
- Solicitante
- Departamento
- Tecnico
- Grupo
- Status
- Prioridade
- Data_Abertura_Chamado
- Data_Vencimento_Chamado
- Data_Conclusao_Chamado
- Nota
- Comentario_Atendimento
- data_criacao_registro
- FlagEmailNota
- FlagEmailSLA
- FlagEmailFechado
- data_resolved

I need to update the `Tblservicedesk`, with values of these 3 columns (FlagEmailNota, FlagEmailSLA, FlagEmailFechado ) from the `Tblservicedesk_temp` table.

All of this 3 columns is NULL in `Tblservicedesk`, and we have values in some columns in `Tblservicedesk_temp`.

I need to use ID_SOLICITAÇÃO as PK.

Comment: i'm trying to create a query with insert and joins, but with no success.

Comment: `Insert into Tblservicedesk ( FlagEmailNota, FlagEmailSLA, FlagEmailFechado ) from Tblservicedesk_temp
where ...`

Comment: Do you want to `INSERT` new records or `UPDATE` existing records? Your question says update, your query says insert...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming both `Tblservicedesk` & `Tblservicedesk_temp` having same columns. You can write update statement to update the three columns (FlagEmailNota, FlagEmailSLA, FlagEmailFechado ).

```
UPDATE tsd
SET
   tsd.FlagEmailNota = tsdt.FlagEmailNota , 
   tsd.FlagEmailSLA = tsdt.FlagEmailSLA, 
   tsd.FlagEmailFechado = tsdt.FlagEmailFechado
FROM 
   Tblservicedesk AS tsd
JOIN
  Tblservicedesk_temp AS tsdt ON tsd.ID_SOLICITAÇÃO = tsdt.ID_SOLICITAÇÃO
```

Since I don't have enough reputation to comment hence i'm posting this as an answer, if this is not what you are looking for please let me know.

Comment: Thank you very much brother. I'm not good in programming. it was really helpful...please, don't go alone, take this rep points with you

Answer (score 2):

```
UPDATE sd
SET sd.FlagEmailNota = sdt.FlagEmailNota,
sd.FlagEmailSLA = sdt.FlagEmailSLA,
sd.FlagEmailFechado = sdt.FlagEmailFechado
FROM dbo.Tblservicedesk AS sd INNER JOIN dbo.Tblservicedesk_temp AS sdt ON sd.ID_Solicitacao = sdt.ID_Solicitacao
```